# Modify QGIS attribute table to behave differently

Tags: qgis, attribute-table

I have 10 data layers of environmental and social country factors - e.g. wastewater etc

I've loaded them into QGIS and manipulated as required.
However, I am now wondering is there a way to manipulate QGIS to be more user-friendly for my specific purpose. For example, when I select a polygon the attribute table would be displayed like so:

| E/S Factor | Indicator |
| --- | --- |
| Waste Management | High |
| Water Stress | Low |
| Air Quality | Medium |

But then if you hover over `Waste Management` you could click it and the attribute table would shift to attribute information about that specific factor:

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| ID | 001 |
| Name | Hello |
| Location | Earth |

So, essentially, a modified attribute table to be a one-click stop for showing all information you need. Initially, just an indicative overview, but when a certain factor is clicked then see that factors associated info.

Comment: Have you looked into using [relations](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/attribute_table.html#creating-one-or-many-to-many-relations)?

Comment: @Matt I wasn't aware this existed - thank you! Do you think it would behave how I somewhat outlined?

Comment: Yes, using form (https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/training_manual/create_vector_data/forms.html#ls-forms) and relation will give you something close but setting it up could be quite a work depending on how your data are organised....